# Adding an object to an array, where the parent object value equals a specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongojs

This may be a limitation of Mongo, for I haven't found a solution to the issue I am having.

Currently, I am using the MongoJS NPM package to make the syntax a bit more streamlined for my Node application. You can see MongoJS here: https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs. Regardless, **I need to ($)push and object to an array, if the array's parent object has a property with a value of x**.

For example:

```
var document = {
  date: '1-8-2017',
  classes: [
    {
      class: 'nursery',
      students: [
        {
          firstName: 'Blah'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make sure not only the date is the selected document in the collection, but also that the class is selected, and then of course I want to push an object into the students array. See my solution, that appears to not be working.

Initial Attempt

```
db.attendance.update({ date: classDocument.date }, {
  $push: {
    classes: [{
      class: studentDetails.class,
        students: [
          studentDetails
        ]
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Further Attempt

```
db.attendance.update({ date: classDocument.date, classes: [{ class: studentDetails.class }] }, {
  $push: {
    students: [
      studentDetails
    ]
  }
});
```

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Daily sermon. Do not nest arrays. There is absolutely no advantage in doing so and in fact you give rise to limitations. Instead this should be a "single" array using all the nested levels as "properties" of the same data. With that you can actually query on the content in a regular way and also match positions with the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) where required. Note that the limitation is and has always been "matching the index to the **first** discovered position only". So that is how you need to actually structure.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend not to use reserved keys as `class` and if you really must, at least surround it with quotes (" or ')

Comment: Thanks guys, I ended up not having nested arrays!